# Combine/concatenate multiple MP4 files, making each file into a chapter

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, handbrake, combine

I am looking to use [handbrake](/questions/tagged/handbrake) to combine 43 short [mp4](/questions/tagged/mp4) files into one larger file. However, I want to ensure that the start of each file is recognized as a chapter. I'd be using [vlc](/questions/tagged/vlc) to play the file.

Comment: Same task here... Can concatenate the files using mp4box but then there's no chapter breaks.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1 https://superuser.com/questions/1320389/updating-mp4-chapter-times-and-names-with-ffmpeg

Comment: A solution on ffmpeg, without handbrake: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/745238/264065

Answer (score 0):

> What format are your video files in ? If they're DVD MPEG-2 then Handbrake can convert them to MP4/M4V or MKV, both of which support chapter markers.
>
> If you already have MP4 files I believe you can use Subler to add chapters or something like Metadata Hootenanny.

Basically it is saying your MP4's needs to have the Chapters created before using handbrake.  You may try Subler to add chapters.  I have never tried Subler so I wouldn't be able to give you any specifics.

http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/311503-Video-format-with-chapter-markers